# What intermediate files can be deleted from the WxWidgets-2.8.12 builds?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

I have rarely used command-line makefiles, usually doing single projects and manually building them.

I'm using Win Xp-sp3 on a build machine with wxWidgets2.8.12 and VS2008, I've created multiple build formats for the libraries (10-total) and this has left about 2.5Gb of space with intermediate files, I used a batch file for creation, but not sure if I'm looking to clean the right files in the correct manner.  When I try and run the cleaning process inside Visual Studio, it does a complete cleaning of intermediate files AND output files. The wxWidgets file structure looks like this:

C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw with the 10 sub folders for the different build types.  I used a simple batch script for creation:

```
echo now building... WxWidgets with debug=y Unicode=y DLL=y Universal=y
rem builds debug with unicode DLLs WXUniversal
nmake -f makefile.vc BUILD=debug UNICODE=1 SHARED=1 WXUNIV=1
rem add clean command to delete INTERMEDIATE files only 
rem (*.o, *.obj, *.res, *.pch. *.pdb, *.ilk ....)
```

I thought that running:

```
nmake -f makefile.vc /clean
```

after each creation block would do the trick, but it only worked on one directory, deleting everything there.

My question is: Am I looking at the right intermediate files to delete in my rem statements? and is there an automatic method to get rid of the intermediate files, but keep the output files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, "clean" target deletes everything. You may want to copy the output files (i.e. libraries, DLLs and PDBs) to some other directory, then "nmake clean" and then maybe move them back.

P.S. Are you sure you need to build wxUniversal at all?

Comment: thanks for the response, about the wxUniversals, I originally thought that I could use them with Netbeans (I know, n00b move!).  I need to save the PDB's? not the precompiled header files PCHs?

Comment: I think VZ meant save what you need to use and remove the rest!

Comment: PDBs are needed for debugging. You don't need to save the PCH files, they're only used for building wxWidgets itself.

Answer (score 0):

VZ have a good solution. Another solution might be making new makefile target (copy the clean target and modify it) and tell it to leave only output file so that you would do

```
nmake -f makefile.vc [OPTIONS]
nmake -f makefile.vc New_target
```

Comment: thanks - one question, If the makefile for the new_target has the same name as the original, should it be located 1 directory level higher than the target, and reference the files in the lower directories?

Comment: why same name for two different tasks in the first place? If you still want that put the new target in different file and run it after the wxWidgets make files i.e nmake -f makefile2.vc